# layout section in adminhtml.xml not working

Tags: admin, module, configuration, adminhtml

I have read the Magento Wiki about the `<adminhtml>` tag is deprecated and new modules should always use `adminhtml.xml` instead.

But I found that some sections, `<layout>` in particular, is not read from `adminhtml.xml` and only works from the `<adminhtml>` tag in `config.xml`.

Am I doing it wrong, or Magento is still in the middle of transition?

Comment: can you show us your config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adminhtml.xml files are processed by the model file `Mage_Admin_Model_Config`. When you look into this file you will see the processing for the acl: `loadAclResources` and the menu items: `getMenuItemLabel`

Sadly just because the node is called `adminhtml` does not mean that it is directly transferable to the `adminhtml.xml` file.

Comment: This is sad. :(

Comment: @Vicary it may be there is a away to do this or in a future version it would work but as far as I know it is just these items.

Comment: Hope for the future, finger crossed.